# Creating a html dropdown list with the contents of a SQLite field

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I am trying to make an SQLite field the contents of a drop down list in html using embedded JavaScript. This is the code I have but it does not work.

```
            <select>
            <option value="default">Select a test to edit</option>
            <script>
            var db = openDatabase('ExamSQL', '1.0', 'database')
            db.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql('SELECT Questions FROM Question',[],function(tx,questions);
                {
                    var len = questions.rows.length, i;
                    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    </script><option value="name"><script>
                        document.write(questions.rows.item(i).text)
                        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=questions.rows.item(i).text
                    </script></option>
                    <script>
                }
            });
            </script>
        </select>
```

Can anyone help?

Edit: I did this after BrokenBinary's comment

```
<select id="section_list">
    <option value="default">Select a section the question is in</option>
    <script>
    var db = openDatabase('ExamSQL', '1.0', 'database')
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT SectionName FROM Section',[],function(tx,sections);
        {   
            var select=document.getElementById('section_list')
            var len = sections.rows.length, i;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.text=sections.rows.item(i).text;
                option.value=sections.rows.item(i).text;
                select.appendChild(option);
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
</select>
```

And it sill doesn't work. Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can't close your `<script>` tag in the middle of your loop. Instead, you should create the `<option>` element in javascript and then append it to your `<select>` element.

So your loop would look something like this:

```js
// Give your select an ID and use it here
var select = document.getElementById('my-select');

var len = questions.rows.length, i;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = questions.rows.item(i).text;
    option.value = questions.rows.item(i).text;
    select.appendChild(option);
}
```